# Reverse linked list python

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, input=None):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self.index = None
        if input is not None:
            for p in input:
                new = Node(p)
                if self.first is None:
                    self.first = new
                else:
                    self.last.next = new
                self.last= new
```

This code makes a linked list from parameter.

```
t = LinkedList([1,2,[3,4],5])
```

will be stored as: 1-2-[3,4]-5      where - sign is data.next reference. 
I need reverse of this list, my idea was to swap elements [0]-[n],[1]-[n-1]..

```
def reverse(self):
    temp = self.first
    self.first = self.last
    self.last = temp
    temp = self.first.next
```

It swaps first and last element and makes temp as next node from start, but I don't know how to continue, how to make this code work ?

Comment: Where are you ever *setting* `self.first`?

Comment: reverse is function of LinkedList, where self.first is declared in  __init__ function.

Comment: But you never assign anything other than `None` to it.

Comment: Eh I saw it, sorry there was mistake.

Comment: Tip:  You can swap two variables `x` and `y` in Python without a temp variable using the statement `x, y = y, x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general algorithm is as follows:

1. Maintain pointers to the start of two lists, an old list and a new list.  Initially the old list contains all the nodes and the new list is empty.
2. Repeatedly remove the first node of the old list and add it to the front of the new list, until the old list is empty and the new list contains all nodes.

The resulting new list will be the reverse of the old list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a working `Node` class and `LinkedList` class along with a `reverse` function that reverses the singly linked list in place. The idea is to change the memory references for each node.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def reverse(self):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current:
            next_node = current.next
            current.next = previous
            previous = current
            current = next_node
        self.head = previous
```

In one pass of the linked list, we swap the pointers of each node by keeping track of the `current` and `previous` nodes. This algorithm won't require a new linked list to be created to store the reversed list and will run in linear time. I hope this helps by giving an alternative linked list reverse implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @andrew's solution by using recursion instead of iteration:

```
def reverse(self):
    def recursive(curr, prev):
        if not curr:  # curr is None
            return prev
        temp = curr.next
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = temp

        return recursive(curr, prev)

    self.head = recursive(curr=self.head, prev=None)
```